# How to add timezone to datetime in Python

Tags: python

```
(datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(hours=8))
```

This code doesn't seem to work in Python 3 when I'm trying to print my local timezone.

Comment: Kindly go through this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

And the easy way is,

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

print("Local time {}".format(utc_dt.astimezone().isoformat()))
```

Comment: @PhillipDev, If you feel that above answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Python docs recommend to use the `pytz` module.

`pip install pytz`

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> dt_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz = pytz.UTC)
>>> print(dt_now)
2020-08-09 07:02:20.863890+00:00
```

Here is the documentation on [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) for more info.